# Can you use SQLite ATTACH and DETACH in Golang?

Tags: go, sqlite

I am using [go-sqlite3](https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3). Can I use [`ATTACH`](http://sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) and `DETACH` in Golang? I don't know how else to use multiple databases than by creating two database connections and joining data in the application:

```
db1, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", "./db1.db")
db2, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", "./db2.db")

// query db1 and db2
// put into map
// join data
```

It would be much easier if you could use:

```
attach database database1.db as db1;
attach database database2.db as db2;

select
  *
from
  db1.SomeTable a
    inner join 
  db2.SomeTable b on b.SomeColumn = a.SomeColumn;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can attach a database, you would do it in SQL after opening the first database (omit error check for brevity):

```
db1, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", "./db1.db")
defer db1.Close()

s := "attach database '/path/to/db2.db' as db2;"

_, err = db.Exec(s)

s = `select *
     from db1.SomeTable a
     inner join db2.SomeTable b on b.SomeColumn = a.SomeColumn; `

results, err := db.Query(s)
defer results.Close()

//process results ...

_, err = db.Exec("detach database db2;")
```

Comment: error: no such table `db1.SomeTable`. which `SomeTable` is actual table name.

Comment: If excution `join` query is db1, there is no need to set db name in `from`, just use table name like this:select *
     from SomeTable a
     inner join db2.SomeTable b on b.SomeColumn = a.SomeColumn;

Answer (score 1):

`no such table` error ***sometimes*** happen because `sql.DB` is a connection pool.

```go
_, err = db.Exec(`ATTACH 'path/to/file.db' AS attached`) // (1)

db.Query(`...`) // (2) try to access 'attached'
```

The `Query()` (2) may happen on different connection than `Exec()` (1).

---

The easiest way to solve this is to request single connection before executing `ATTACH`

```go
conn, err := db.Conn(ctx)
defer conn.Close()
conn.ExecContext(`..ATTACH..`)
```

subsequent use of `conn` will have the attached DB.

---

A more complex alternative is to create a new driver that wraps the original driver, but the new driver does some extra initialization like ATTACH before passing the new connection to `sql.DB`.

for example: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3#hdr-Go_SQlite3_Extensions